# Need help with optimization problem involving a triangle and its lengths.

Tags: calculus

Find the rectangle of maximum area that can be inscribed in a right triangle with legs of length a=43 and b=44 if the sides of the rectangle x,y are parallel to the legs of the triangle, as in the figure.

Okay, I know that I should first draw out an image of everything so that I can visual what it is I have and what it is I need. But after that I get lost. Any help is appreciated.

This triangle was provided in the question [image]

Comment: Can you try to attach the diagram you attempted?

Comment: How do I attach an image?

Comment: When you [edit] this post, you can look at the toolbar just under the title, the 6th icon from the left allows you to add an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the triangle can be described on the plane used for graphing ($x$ axis horizontal, $y$ axis vertical) as being bounded by the $x$ and $y$ axes and the line $y = 43 - (43/44) x$.

The area of a rectangle defined by a point on that line and the origin is:

$A = x y = 43 x - 43/44 x^2$.

The derivative is:

${\partial A \over \partial x} = 43 - {2 \cdot 43 \over 44} x$.

Set this derivative to zero and find $x = 22$.

Comment: What is a Cartesian plane?